# Django sum on query set

Tags: django, django-orm, django-annotate

I have a queryset in django with condition as follows:

```
query_set = MyModel.objects.annotate(TWWByRuns=(
    Case(
        When(Q(toss_winner=F('winner')) & Q(win_by_runs=0), then=1),
        output_field=FloatField(), default=0)
    )
).values('TWWByRuns')
```

I would like to use django built-in sum function to add whenever the value in the `query_set` equals to 1 as in when `then=1`. I know to use the sum function without conditionals but here since I have condition where should I use the sum function in this `query_set`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case, it makes more sense to *count*:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(toss_winner=F('winner'), win_by_runs=0).count()
```

We here thus simply check how many `MyModel` records satisfy the given condition.

Comment: So this condition is similar to checking whether MyModel.toss_winner = MyModel.winner and MyModel.win_by_runs = 0?

Comment: @Laxman: yes. We thus count the number of `MyModel` records, for which that condition holds.

Comment: Ok. One last question. How to check not equal to in django? Because according to my understanding there is no '!=' operator in django.

Comment: To check win_by_runs != 0 what should be the operator?

Comment: @Laxman: you negate that part of the query, like `MyModel.objects.filter(toss_winner=F('winner'), ~Q(win_by_runs=0)).count()`.

Comment: I tried that before. I got the following error: `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`.

Comment: @Laxman: sorry, the arguments indeed should be swapped, so `MyModel.objects.filter(~Q(win_by_runs=0), toss_winner=F('winner')).count()`.

Comment: Thank you! I did not think properly about the error! That solved it.